# How to include a set of four subplots (2x2) as one subplot of another set of (2x2) subplots using groupplots?

Tags: plot, groupplots, embedding, subplot

What I am looking for is something like this:
[image]

and I have tried the next MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{groupplot}[
         group style={group size=2 by 2},
         cycle multiindex* list = {very thick\nextlist red\nextlist 
         only 
         marks\nextlist}
     ] 
     \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
     \nextgroupplot[cycle list = {red, blue}] \addplot {x}; \addplot 
     {x^2};
     \nextgroupplot \addplot[green] {x}; \addplot {x^2};
     \nextgrouplot %Here I am not sure what to do
        \begin{groupplot}[
                            group style={group size=2 by 2},
                            cycle multiindex* list = {very 
                            thick\nextlist red\nextlist only 
                           marks\nextlist}
                           ]
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
       \end{groupplot}
     \end{groupplot}
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and ugly solution, use a `scope` around the second `groupplot`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}    
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{groupplot}[
        at={(0,0)},
         group style={group size=2 by 2},
         cycle multiindex* list = {very thick\nextlist red\nextlist 
         only 
         marks\nextlist}
     ] 
     \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
     \nextgroupplot[cycle list = {red, blue}] \addplot {x}; \addplot 
     {x^2};
     \nextgroupplot \addplot[green] {x}; \addplot {x^2};
     \end{groupplot}
     \begin{scope}[xshift=7.9cm,yshift=-3.8cm,scale=1]
        \begin{groupplot}[scale=0.5,
                            group style={group size=2 by 2},
                            cycle multiindex* list = {very 
                            thick\nextlist red\nextlist only 
                           marks\nextlist}
                           ]
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
       \end{groupplot}
       \end{scope}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

With a second look at your question I would advise the following process : 
- Create 1 document per image for `a)`, `b)`, and `c)` using an `axis` environment
- Create 1 document for image `d)` using a `groupplot`
- Assemble them in your final document using the `figure` and `subfigure` environments.

The `Image.tex` file should look like

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{style1/.style={cycle multiindex* list = {very thick\nextlist red\nextlist only marks\nextlist}}}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[style1]
        \addplot {x};
        \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[style1,cycle list = {red, blue}]
  \addplot{x};
  \addplot{x^2};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[style1]
\addplot[green] {x};
\addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}     
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},style1]
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
       \end{groupplot}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and in your main document, you should use something like

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=1]{Image.pdf}
\end{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=2]{Image.pdf}
\end{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=3]{Image.pdf}
\end{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[page=4,scale=0.5]{Image.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of Bamboo's first code, where instead of explicit `xshift` and `yshift`, I use the `group name` feature, make an invisible axis in the "big" groupplot and place the first small groupplot on the top left corner of that invisible axis. Instead of using `scale` I set appropriate widths for small groupplots.

To get the subcaptions you could load the `subcaption` package and use `\subcaption{}` in the `title`. Some modifications of the `title style` is needed for that.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
           group size=2 by 2,
           group name=g, % add a name to each axis
           vertical sep=1cm,
           horizontal sep=1cm
        },
        width=0.4\textwidth,
        scale only axis,
        cycle multiindex* list = {
            very thick\nextlist
            red\nextlist 
            only marks\nextlist
          },
        title style={
          text width=6cm,
          below=12pt,
          at={(0.5,0)}
        }
     ] 
     \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{}}]
         \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
     \nextgroupplot[
          title={\subcaption{}},
          cycle list = {red, blue}]
         \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
     \nextgroupplot[title={\subcaption{}}] \addplot[green] {x}; \addplot {x^2};
     \nextgroupplot[hide axis,title={\subcaption{}}] % make an empty axis
     \end{groupplot}
     \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
           group size=2 by 2,
           horizontal sep=1cm,
           vertical sep=1cm,
        },
        width={0.5*(0.4\textwidth-1cm)}, % (width of big subplot minus horizontal sep of this group)  divided by 2
        scale only axis,
        cycle multiindex* list = {
            very thick\nextlist
            red\nextlist 
            only marks\nextlist
          }
                           ]
           \nextgroupplot[at={(g c2r2.north west)},anchor=north west]
               \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
           \nextgroupplot \addplot {x}; \addplot {x^2};
       \end{groupplot}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Main caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]